# Copy files to network share with WiX

Tags: wix, network-share

As a part of my project, the installer has to copy files to network share(\system_name\Folder). I have tried it using the `<Directory>` element defining the path to the share (NetHoodFolder property) but it's throwing an error.

```
Error   5   ICE64: The directory SP9381 is in the user profile but is not listed in the RemoveFile table.   C:\Wix\MainProject\MainProject\Product.wxs  25  1   MainProject
```

Can we do the same using  element ? Is there any other way to copy files to network share?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy files to a network share but there are a number of limitations. First, to get around the ICE issue, try structuring your directory tree like so:

```
<Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Source='SourceDir'>
   <Directory Id='ProgramFilesFolder' Name='PFiles'>
      <Directory Id='NETWORKSHAREFOLDER' Name='network'>
   </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Then somehow you need to get the network share to be known. You could ask in the UI or take it from the command-line or whatever. I hardcoded the string in my test case (definitely not recommended for reals):

```
<Property Id='NETSHARE' Value='\\server\share\folder' />
<SetDirectory Id='NETWORKSHAREFOLDER' Value='[NETSHARE]' />
```

If you wanted to pass it on the command line, don't add any of the above, just do:

```
msiexec /i path\to\your.msi NETWORKSHAREFOLDER="\\server\share\folder"
```

Basically, just root your NETWORKSHAREFOLDER in a well known folder and then change it later as explained above.