# WIX : CostFinalize throws error when trying to create file on remote server

Tags: database, installation, wix

We are using WIX tool for installers. We have option to create database on remote server.

When we try to create DB on remote server on drive which does not exists on the server from where we are deploying, installer throws error saying 'Invalid drive '.

In log we found CostFinalize is failing because this custom action tries to validate space on local server.

Has anyone faced this issue? Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **cannot** install to a drive letter that does not exist. Additionally, network shares mapped to drive letters can be tricky to access from the system service because the drive letter may be only visible to the user that created the drive.

However, it is possible to install files to a network folder. There are details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15956971/23852). That will provide a far more robust solution rather than relying on network shares mapped to drives to be correct.